# FISH: How to set a specific $fish_function_path while launching fish?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, fish

I'm trying to use the [sshrc](https://github.com/Russell91/sshrc) to execute `fish` with my own defined functions at the remote server.

I know there is a `$fish_function_path` variable that I can modify to prepend my custom path with my functions, but this variable seems global and I don't want to affect other `fish` users.

Is there any way to change this variable only for my single fish session or any other ways to use my fish functions only for a single session?

I have also tried setting and environment variable from the outer shell: `fish_functions_path="$MY_FUNCTIONS_PATH" fish` but it seems environment variables don't affect those inner variables of fish.

Used this [docs](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html).

Thanks!

Comment: Five years too late, but the reason that your `fish_functions_path="$MY_FUNCTIONS_PATH" fish` didn't work is that there is a typo in it (extra `s` after `function`).  With the correct variable name, that works for me.  It's also possible that something changed in `fish` in the last 5 years, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables, including `$fish_function_path`, are per-session. You might be thinking of universal variables, which are shared across sessions for a given user.

It should be fine to modify `$fish_function_path` for a given instance of fish - it won't affect any others.

Comment: Ok, but how can I execute fish AND change the `$fish_function_path` in one command? If I change this variable with `fish -c` before I go interactive with `exec fish` it reveals that I've changed the variable universally (even without `set -U` flag`). What exactly should I execute in the outer shell?

Comment: From the `man set`: _If a variable is explicitly set to either universal, global or local, that setting will be honored. If a variable of the same name exists in a different scope, that variable will not be changed._ So if the `$fish_function_path` is predefined as a universal variable, I will always edit it as a universal variable.

Comment: It seems I can call `set -l fish_function_path ...` at the start of the `fish` session to avoid modifying it globally. But the problem is how to call it automatically. I mean I would like to use something like `fish -i -c "the command at the start"`

Comment: I can't think of how to do this with stock fish. Can you add some code to your remote `~/.config/fish/config.fish` that checks some custom environment variable and modifies `$fish_function_path`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. One of the requirements is not to modify any default configs at the server. I've made some solution for now: I just alter the `$HOME` variable at sshrc and then I run fish. I copy all my configs to this tmp `$HOME`. So, all programs I run from fish do use configuration files of mine. Not a great idea, I think. As a bonus, I'm getting a pure home directory so there are only my histories and other runtime stuff. Made it as a [github repository](https://github.com/flashhhh/konfig).